# Why does $x^7 = 5$ (mod 11) simplify into $5x^3 = 1$ (mod 11)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was struggling on a question I found in my math book so I looked at the answers which contained:

... We only need to solve $x^7 = 5$ (mod 11) or $5x^3 = 1$ (mod 11) ...

With no further explanation.

Comment: multiply both sides by $x^3$ and apply Fermat's little theorem

Comment: **Hint** $\ x^{\large 7}\equiv x^{\large -3}\,$ if $\,x\not \equiv 0,\,$ by little Fermat.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I'm amused why you comment on a solved question that's almost a year old, but thanks regardless

Comment: @Krish  Answers and comments help many readers, not only the original asker (e.g. readers who find the question from search engines).

Comment: @BillDubuque My point was that this question has already been sufficiently commented on, but I digress. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&x^7\equiv 5\;(\text{mod}\;11)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^3{\,\cdot\,}x^7\equiv 5x^3\;(\text{mod}\;11)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^{10}\equiv 5x^3\;(\text{mod}\;11)\\[4pt]
\therefore\;\;\,&5x^3\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;11)
&&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\text{$
\bigl($by Fermat's little Theorem, which is applicable}\\[0pt]
&&&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\text{since $x^7\equiv 5\;(\text{mod}\;11)$ implies $x\not\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;11)\bigr)$}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: To be very nitpicky, the third line does not imply the fourth, because (devoid of the original context), $x$ might be $0$.

Comment: From the first line, it follows that $x$ is nonzero, mod $11$.

Comment: I hoped my parenthetical made it clear that I am not disputing the correctness, only the presentation.  When I read a chain of implications $A \implies B \implies C$, I take it to mean that $B \implies C$ rather than $A \land B \implies C$.  There is probably some room for disagreement; I’m just saying it would be better to establish the nonzero-ness of $x$ in advance of the one-liner.

Comment: I think it's acceptable to freely use the results from any prior step in any later step. I expect the reader to look back, as needed.

Comment: @Erick Wong  since x raised to some nonzero poweris nonzero it follows it's not 0.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Yes, I am entirely aware of this.  This came down to a slight disagreement in how “$A\implies B\implies C$” should be interpreted.  The answer has since been edited to eliminate any ambiguity, so I have no objections.

Comment: It literally hasn't changed more than 9 characters in the MathJaX   $$A\implies B\land B\implies C$$

Comment: I understand Erick Wong's point. What we need is a "strong implies" symbol to allow results from any prior steps. Lacking such a symbol, I think it's informally acceptable (but not in the context of symbolic logic) to use the ordinary implies symbol in this stronger sense.

Comment: Partially what overset and labelling is for I think. is $$\boldsymbol{\overset{(1)}{\implies}}$$ strong enough.

Comment: That would work.